# How many hours of gameplay for Tales of the Yawning Portal?

Tags: tales-from-the-yawning-portal

Has anyone run all of the Tales from the Yawning Portal? How many hours would you estimate it takes?

I would guess somewhere about 18-20 hours. From what I have read elsewhere, Sunless Citadel could be done in about 9-10 hours.

The Forge of Fury is longer, all I have read is that people say the each of the lower levels take a really long time.

I haven't found estimates on the other chapters.

The reason I ask is because I am going to visit a friend in another state I will be there from Saturday to Wednesday and I am trying to figure out how much we can get done in that time if we are mostly doing marathon gaming sessions each day (Except Wednesday).

We really want to make sure we don't start an adventure get like halfway through and then we have to just leave it off there because I need to catch my flight home.

Thanks

Comment: What edition of D&D are you playing?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Be sure to check out the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you have any questions.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Tales from the Yawning Portal is an adventure for the 5th edition, isn't it?

Comment: @enkryptor I think it may have been in past editions as well. Regardless, we shouldn't guess and OP has to be the one to tell us. That rule should still apply here.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose: I'm pretty sure TFTYP as a whole has never been in past editions - it's just that some of the adventures within it are converted from older editions. Still, we can't guess, so we'll have to wait for OP to return and confirm that they're playing 5e.